# Let $X=\mathbb{R^2}-\{0\}$ and $Y=S^1 \cup\{[0,1]\times\{0\}\}$. Prove or Disprove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R^2}-\{0\}$ and $Y=S^1 \cup\{[0,1]\times\{0\}\}$.
Prove or Disprove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

My thoughts:

Since X is the punctured plane, in terms of retraction, I believe that $S^1$ is a deformation retact of $X$, Similarly, the space $Y$ is the unit circle with an extra "strip" along the $x- axis$ same as the radius. And so  $S^1$ is a deformation retract of $Y$ as well.

As a result, the fundamental groups of both $X$ and $Y$ are  isomorphic to the fundamental group of the unit circle $\pi_1(X,x_0) \approx \mathbb{Z} \approx \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ .
Does this isomorphism guarantee a homeomorphism between the spaces $X$ and $Y$?
if not, Is there a way to appraoch it without involving fundamental groups?

Comment: With respect to your last question: non-homeomorphic spaces may have isomorphic fundamental groups, like a point and the unit disk, for example (or your two spaces!)

Comment: Also with respect to your last question: A famous problem of mathematics is: Suppose $M$ is a three-dimensional manifold with no boundary and a trivial fundamental group.  Must $M$ be homeomorphic to $S^3$? (A three-dimensional manifold is a space that is everywhere _locally_ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$.) This question was unanswered for nearly a hundred years! (See: [Poincaré conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture).) The corresponding question about $S^2$ was resolved long ago, but for $S^4$ the answer is still unknown!

Answer (score 5):

You can disconnect $Y$ by removing two points but if you remove two points to $X$ it is always connected.

Comment: And since Taking two points from X does not make it disconnected, they cannot be homeomorphic?

Comment: yes, they cannot. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an homeomorphism, its restriction to $X-\{x_1,...,x_p\}\rightarrow Y-\{f(x_1),...,f(x_p)\}$ is also an homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I I understand now

Comment: Why two points ? I thought we could remove $(1,0)$ from $Y$ to make it disconnected.

Answer (score 5):

$Y$ is compact, but $X$ isn't.

But $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent. Both have $S^1$ as
a deformation retract.

Comment: I realized. I guess this shows isomorphism between fundamental group does not necessarily say the space are homeomorphic. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$HINT:$ Deleting the point $(1,0)$ from $Y$ results it disconnected. Can you find such point in $X$?